# SQL Server 2016+ updating large data sets with out primary keys

Tags: sql-server, etl

I currently ETL 3.2 billion rows of data daily and then distribute it.  75% of this data is static in that it does not change more than once in a 48 hour period but some of it changes more frequently.  My issue is that almost all of this data does not contain a primary key from the source (174 distinct unique sources) So we mostly just dump and load nightly.  Now we are getting requests to update the datasets more often to account for the changes that do occur more often.  On some of the smaller tables we have created a round robin procedure that loads one table while the other is being used and then when it finishes it swaps the table pointer so I never effectively querying and loading the same table at the same time. This works but some of the new tables have many API's with direct queries pointing at them. This makes the round robin proc solution less desirable.  Any one have any thoughts on how I might address this.. just to be clear and remind everyone I do not effectively have a primary key so I cannot just update the data that changed and some of the tables contain 50+ rows so calculating a change at the row level is not really possible either (unless I am just missing something)

Comment: Perhaps partition switching as discussed [here](https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/).